# Extract graphs from PDFs

Tags: image-manipulation, pdf

I have a situation where I need to extract images from lots of PDF files and display them on a website. My PDFs have "regular" images as well as lots of graphs.

I used [pdf2xml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf2xml/) and it pulls out the images in jpeg, ppm, pbm and vec formats. I see the "regular" images being extracted (for the most part) as jpeg/ppm/pbm, but I don't see the graphs being there - and so I am guessing that pdf2xml is storing them as .vec files.

So the question is how to I get my graphs? I used `convert` that comes with imagemagick to convert .vec to jpeg/png etc  but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried pdf2xml, but browsing through its files on SourceForge, I found [vec2svg-2.py](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf2xml/files/misc/vec2svg-2.py/download), which appears to be a Python script to convert .vec files to .svg.  You should have no difficulty converting [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) to whatever format you need.

```
python vec2svg-2.py -i file.vec -o file.svg
```

Comment: Very good observation ! Seems like it will do the job for me. Thanks !